# Angular prevent mocking of $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm writing some tests for an Angular app connecting to a REST API, which we're also developing. In this case I'm actually wanting to do an integration test rather than a unit test so I don't want to have the `$http` service mocked. I want to do a real AJAX request and test the response is what we're expecting it to be.

I can't simply remove `angular-mock.js` as this is required for other tests, is there a way to force angular to use the real service rather than replacing with the mocked one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the "passThrough" option? It was designed specifically for this purpose:

> > As opposed to unit-testing, in an end-to-end testing scenario or in scenario when an application is being developed with the real backend api replaced with a mock, it is often desirable for certain category of requests to bypass the mock and issue a real http request (e.g. to fetch templates or static files from the webserver). To configure the backend with this behavior use the `passThrough` request handler of `when` instead of `respond`.

e.g.:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/my-resource\/.*/).passThrough();
```